# IE7 vertical background-position bug

Tags: internet-explorer, background

I'm using background-positions on a sprite for nav images. It looks great in chrome, safari, ff, etc. The horizontal property seems to work in IE but not the vertical. It's all over the place. Conversely, I have almost the exact same code on a different site but [that](http://jusbarseattle.com) sprite was setup horizontally.

Here's the css. I added the background-position-x/y as a potential fix but IE doesn't seem to be affected by that either (unless there's a caching bug with the Winebottler IE7 install). I'm new so that'll explain any noob stuff in this:

```
#menu-item-16 a {
background-image: url("images/csg.png");
background-position: 0 -510px;   
background-position-x: 0;
background-position-y: -510px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 400px auto;
display: block;
height: 80px;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: -13px;
outline: none;
padding: 0;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 400px;
}
#menu-item-16 a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -638px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: -638px;
}
#menu-item-24 a {
    background-image: url("images/csg.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px auto;
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 400px;
}
#menu-item-24 a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -128px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: -128px;
}
#menu-item-15 a {
    background-image: url("images/csg.png");
    background-position: 0 -1025px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: -1025px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px auto;
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: -13px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 400px;
}
#menu-item-15 a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -1153px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: -1153px;
}
#menu-item-13 a {
    background-image: url("images/csg.png");
    background-position: 0 -1282px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: -1282px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px auto;
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: -13px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 400px;
}
#menu-item-13 a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -1409px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: -1409px;
}
#menu-item-14 a {
    background-image: url("images/csg.png");
    background-position: 0 -769px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: -769px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px auto;
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: -13px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 400px;
}
#menu-item-14 a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -897px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: -897px;
}
#menu-item-28 a {
    background-image: url("images/csg.png");
    background-position: 0 -257px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: -257px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px auto;
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: -13px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 400px;
}
#menu-item-28 a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -385px;
    background-position-x: 0;
    background-position-y: -385px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

by the way, your code above isn't going to work well because css code looks at your last entry that didn't break.

```
background-position: 0 0;
background-position-x: 0;
background-position-y: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an alt style sheet that adjusted the background positions just for IE. The weird thing is, I initially used [this](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) sprite generator to save me time. The coordinates it spit out on its own css were way off for FF, Chrome, etc. But they were spot on for IE - comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

first of all background-position-x and background-position-y doesn't work in Firefox. it works like this however for cross browsers:

```
background-position-x: 300px;
background-position: 300px 0;
background-position-y: 300px;
background-position: 0 300px;
```

IE and Chrome support background-position-x and background-position-y, however, IE doesn't work well when you try to change background-position-y on events. you can try the above code to replace the explicitly positioning with x and y coordinates.